# Store [Date: String] Dictionary to UserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, userdefaults

I am trying to store `[Date: String]` dictionary in `UserDefaults` by using `JSONEncoder`, but during building returns error:

> error: Illegal instruction: 4 (in target 'myProject' from project 'myProject')

How to store `[Date: String]` dictionary in `UserDefaults` properly?

Below is code I used:

```
if let transDict = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "TransLedger") {
    print("UPDATE LEDGER")
    var oldDict = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Date: String].self, from: transDict)
    oldDict[transDate!] = productName
              
    let oldData = try! JSONEncoder().encode(oldDict)              
    UserDefaults.standard.set(oldData, forKey: "TransLedger")
}
```

Comment: Don’t throw away the error.

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the error? I see three uses of `!` in your code. Bad practice.

Comment: Looks like this error has no relation with this code. Is error repeat after you remove this code?

Comment: @FuzzzzyBoy when I remove this code, it builds and runs normally without error. I also tried to add docatch, but it doesn't help at all. I think it is problem with [Date: String] way of dictionary declaration, because when I try to declare like [String:String] it works perfectly. Therefore I want to know khow properly to declare [Date: String] and store in Userdefaults.

Comment: Date do not convert in JSON. You have to handle dates manually in coding/decoding

Comment: @PtitXav `Date` conforms to both `Codable` and `Decodable`. Nothing needs to be done manually. The OP's code to decode and encode a `[Date: String]` is just fine as-is.

Comment: @HangarRash : so may be the encoding strategy should be defined.

Comment: @PtitXav While you can specify the JSON date encoding strategy if desired, the default works just fine in a case such as the OP's since the JSON isn't being sent anywhere that requires a specific strategy. But the error in the question is definitely not being caused by the simple encoding and decoding of a `[Date: String]` dictionary. Unfortunately the OP never replied to my first comment asking for clarification on which line is actually causing the crash.

Comment: @HangarRash sorry for late reply. It didn't indicate any error in any line of code. It was just returned error in build window. Actually I solved this issue by setting 2 separate arrays (date and string) in userdefaults and then combined them into dictionary after decoding back.

Answer (score -1):

You can store a 'dictionary' of [String:Any] or [Date:String] in 'UserDefaults' where you can use date as a key(String or Date) and can add value for the same. If you want to use 'date' itself as a key then also it's fine.

'UserDefaults' itself provides a function to store objects so instead of using JSON Decoder, use the following function:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(value: Any?, forKey: String)
```

so your working code will look like this:

```
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        if let transDict = userDefaults.object(forKey: "TransLedger") as? [String:Any] {
            print("UPDATE LEDGER")
            // update product name
            transDict[transDate!] = productName // transDate key depends on what format of dictionary i.e [String:Any] or [Date:String] you are using so you can update it accordingly
            // now update object in UserDefaults
            userDefaults.set(transDict, forKey: "TransLedger")
        }
```

Comment: thank you for advice, but it didin't work for me as well. I choose the way to setup 2 arrays in userdefaults and them combine them into dictionary after decoding.